# Boot up with USB or external hard drive

Tags: security

Can Ubuntu be used in a computer with no internal hard drive?
Using only a USB or external hard drive

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Ubuntu as a live disk only and partition storage space for files and saved sessions (if your flashdrive is big enough--at least 8gb). Not going to be very good for long term, but fine for a while.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent

Any OS is going to run slower off of a flash drive so I would recommend using 3.0 if you have it.